# How can I have realistically bending/flexing paper?

Tags: unity, animation, gameobject

I am a new hobbyist to Unity and I working on a game where the player goes around picking up clues in the form of paper notes to solve a mystery.

So far, thanks to the help I got here, I was able to animate a note made from a UI canvas and an image in game world to fly and rotate to align itself in front of the first person camera.

Although, it looks nice, it still looks like a rigid plank of wood rather than a piece of paper. Is there a way I could bend/flew/distort the canvas to give the illusion of a piece of paper rather than piece of wood?

Is it possible to bend a canvas or should I go towards another solution, like using an actual plane or quad during the animation effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use Cloth to simulate this, similar to a flag blowing in the wind.

Flag blowing in the wind:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/935743/how-do-you-make-a-flag-blow-in-wind-unity5.html

Youtube tutorial on working with Cloth:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ8DgasVT_M

Unity Cloth Manual:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cloth.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Really hope it works. Do you think it can be applied to  a UI game world canvas ?